# Why this replacement rule {{I, 0}, {0, -I}} /. {a_, b_ ?Conjugate[a]} -> c does not work?

Tags: replacement, pattern-matching

I want to make a replamement in a $2\times2$ matrix only if the elements on the main diagonal are conjugates of each other. Why does not this work and how can I make it work?

Answer (score 3):

Because `a` and `b` match `{I, 0}` and `{0, -I}`, not the diagonal elements.

```
{{I, 0}, {0, -I}} /. {{a_, _}, {_, b_}} /; b == Conjugate[a] :> c
(* c *)
```